# Rails Assets Pipeline: Generate two images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, retina-display

I would like to use only retina images in my assets folder and get the Assets Pipeline to generate the non-retina versions.

Is there a clean way for a post-processor to generate two assets and add a suffix to one of them ?

Thanks !